# Three JS WebXR on Headset

Tags: virtual-reality

I have a three JS app which is VR enabled.

If anyone has any experience or success in deploying to a VR headset, it would be great to get some guidance or direction.

1. Firstly, how can I visualize the deployed threeJS VR enabled app on a VR headset. The application is deployed on a server https.
2. I have access to few devices including HTC Vive, Vive Focus, HoloLens and MagicLeap. Have tried with HTC Vice but I believe it does not have a browser.
3. How to debug using suitable headset.
4. I have streamVR installed.

Have anyone been successful in deploying a threeJS app on anyone of the mentioned devices.

Thank you